# Unexpected identifier and Unexpected token export when using babel standalone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I was trying using 'Babel standalone' to import module but getting `Unexpected identifier` and `Unexpected token export`, I can't figure it out why.

Importing is fine on other project which didn't use Babel, I mean vanilla JavaScript, anyway. Here is my code

```html
<script src="dep/babel-standalone-6-min.js"></script>
<script src="dep/react.production-18.min.js"></script>
<script src="dep/react-dom.production-18.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" data-presets="react"
    data-type="module" src="react/main.jsx"></script>
<script type="text/jsx" data-presets="react"
    data-type="module" src="react/o-module.jsx"></script>
```

```js
// main.jsx
import oModule from './o-module.jsx'
```

```js
// o-module.jsx
export default () => {...}
```